# Javascript: How to convert opencv mat to tensor?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, opencv, image-processing, tensorflow.js

Does anybody know how to convert an opencv.js mat into a tensor so I can feed it into my tensorflow.js classifier?

The following code shows what I did to read in and preprocess the image I want to classify:

```
img_array = cv.imread(document.getElementById('picture1'), cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
cv.cvtColor(img_array, img_array, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
let dsize = new cv.Size(100, 100);
cv.resize(img_array, img_array, dsize);
```

My classifier needs a tensor of shape (1, 100, 100, 1) as an input and I do not know how to convert the cv mat into a tensorflow.js tensor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An image object has a properties `data` that can be used to get all pixels values in a flattened array. To construct a tensor, the following can be used

```
const src = cv.imread(imageSource)

const tensor = tf.tensor(src.data, [src.rows, src.cols, -1])
```

Comment: @Valentin maybe you would read it https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers